# How to move large amount of select options to another select control using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link above a duel list box control that is 'Select All'.  The functionality is to move the `<select>` options from one select to another select.

The jQuery moves from the source to the destination and has worked fine, but now there are over 100,000 records in the source `<select>`, and causes a

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

in Chrome and an unresponsive script popup in Firefox.  Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#' + source + ' option').remove().appendTo('#' + destination).removeAttr('selected');
```

Is there a way I can do this to limit the impact on the browser and not cause problems with large amount of `<option>`s?

Comment: The solution is to come up with some other UI widget to allow your users to access - for whatever reason you have - 100k options.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what type of a UI would have over 100,000 option elements? I've never even seen over 1,000.

Comment: I'll admit it's strange, this code was put in a while back.  It lists all the company's plans 1000+ customers with 10 - 50 plans each, you can see how this would accumulate.  The UI has a dueling list box setup, so you can run a report on 1 of the plans or all of them, in this case over 100,000.

Comment: JSFiddle with `select` with 100k options https://jsfiddle.net/7jqkpf66/. Browser crashes when trying to open.

Comment: @Moogs, ouch, yeah.  Mine loads fine though, all the options are coming directly formatted from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than parsing row by row I'd just copy the entire HTML from the source to the destination and then delete the html from the source. I'm not totally sure what you're doing with the active class but you can probably just add a addClass() or removeClass() as nessecary.

```
$('#' + destination).html($('#' + source + ' option').html());
$('#' + source + ' option').html('');
```

Here's a jsFiddle with a working example, all though it doesn't have 100,000 options. https://jsfiddle.net/j9qtej9r/

Comment: As long as it works well this is what I would go with. You'd think the formal method would be more efficient, but doing raw HTML at least means it's handled by the browser's native code and not JavaScript, so might be better as a singular operation.

Comment: @efarley, interesting idea, I like it!  The only issue though, is since it's a dual list box, there could have already been a couple of items selected and in the 'destination' and those would be lost.

Comment: Easy fix, then just make it $('#' + destination).html($('#' + destination).html() + $('#' + source + ' option').html()); See my updated jsFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/j9qtej9r/3/ The only possible issue is that they will be out of order so you might still need to run something to order the two lists together.

Comment: An all around better solution would be to break that list up into many lists. Of course that might be easier said then done, but why couldn't you make a list for each customer that contains only that customers plans. You'd have many short lists instead of one massive unmanageable list.

Comment: @efarley, doh!  I need a coffee, yep, will try just appending the html.  I don't think making 1000s of lists will work, but you've got me thinking about doing something along that line.  Ultimately having 100,000+ items, is not scalable, what happens if we get 500,000?  Thanks so much for your ideas!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but would like to join the discussion. I can't even seem to build a select statement that can open in google chrome using jquery. My code is

```
function selectBuild() {
html = '<select id="select1">';
for (i=0;i<100001;i++) {
    html += '<option>' + i + '</option>';
}
html += '</select>';
$('#selectdiv').html(html);
html ='';
}
```

Perhaps you could iterate all of the options to an array and reprint that array? SOmething like

```
var options = new Array();
$('#'+source+' option').each(function() { options.push($(this).val()); });
html = '<select id="' + destination + '">';
$(options).each(function(index,value) { html+='<option>'+value+'</option>'; });
html += '</select>';

$('#div').html(html);
```